# postgresql field concatenate with delimiter

Tags: postgresql, concatenation, delimiter, string-function

Figure :

[image]

I'm sorry I created Google Translation
This enables the character to combine?
It "," it is separated on the column
While merging the col1 and col2 "|" To be separated

Comment: Do you have any identity column ??

Comment: Yes, I have. Column number starting at 1, column name : col0

Comment: You should at least try my answer

Answer (score 2):

With following data

```
|     col1 |     col2 |
|----------|----------|
| aa,bb,cc | 11,22,33 |
| dd,ee,ff | 44,55,66 |
```

You can use PostgreSQL's [string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html) like below

```
SELECT string_agg(col1 || '|' || col2, ',') col
FROM (
    SELECT unnest(regexp_split_to_array(col1, ',')) col1
          ,unnest(regexp_split_to_array(col2, ',')) col2
          ,row_number() OVER () rn
    FROM table_name
    ) t
GROUP BY rn
```

to get the desired output as

```
|               col |
|-------------------|
| aa|11,bb|22,cc|33 |
| dd|44,ee|55,ff|66 |
```

---

[**`SqlFiddle`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/15c35/2)